# Find the Co-ordinates of the stationary points on the curve $f(x)=2x^3-4x^2+2$

Tags: implicit-differentiation

Find the Co-ordinates of the stationary points on the curve $$f(x)=2x^3-4x^2+2$$

What I did was to differentiate $f(x)$ then factorise to find to possible $x$ values then put those two values into $f(x)$.

Although I came out with $$f(0) = 2,$$ $$f(4/3) = 13.85185$$

Where have I gone wrong? Thanks

Comment: You have a different equation in the title and text. Please correct this.

Comment: Done sorry, i edited the questions title, although i forgot i also needed to edit the text.

Comment: Your method is correct, if you are setting the derivative equal to $0$ which I think you are. Just check the sign of the second value you obtain.

Comment: I double check that it would be positive, Are you saying it should be negative or just make sure?

Comment: EDIT: I mean the second value of $x$ you obtain should be negative.

Comment: It is i missed a - sign thank you

Comment: Yes with the edited equation you have the correct $x$ co-ordinates. However, I don't agree with the value of $f(4/3)$.

Comment: Also please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9017/67881 in concern of typos in questions after answers have been posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is correct. You should obtain:
$$
f^\prime(x) = 0\quad\iff\quad 2x(3x+4) = 0
$$
which is true for $x=0$ and $x=-4/3$. As Stephen pointed out, I think you made a mistake in the sign of your second value. The associated ordinates correspond to $f(x)$ for both values.

Comment: It should have been -4x^2, how would this affect that? thanks

Comment: You should make sure you wrote the right equation before posting... If it is $-4x^2$ then you are right on the abscissa.